# How to split a data frame into sub data frames of unequal size in a single dataframe

Tags: r

i have an excel file with 10000 rows by 7 columns and need to split based on a specific column and split 10000*7 into some n of n*7 sets and all the sets should be in single data frame and the set sizes are not same. and the names of the columns should be appended based on a specific column name

the sample data that i have in excel.xlsx format is shown below:

```
 C1.xlsx (worksheet:C_1)   
A  B  C  D  E              
1  4  6  8  C_1             
3  56 7  8  C_1             
2  4  6  1  C_1             
2  4  6  1  C_2     
2  3  6  8  C_2     
7  8  3  4  C_2     
2  3  6  8  C_2
1  4  6  8  C_2
2  3  5  6  C_2
3  4  6  7  C_2
1  9  6  1  C_2
3  4  2  7  C_3
2  1  5  1  C_3
```

the desired excel sheet should be as shown below

```
C1splitted.xlsx (worksheet: sheet 1)   
C_1.A  C_1.B  C_1.C  C_1.D  C_1.E  C_2.A  C_2.B  C_2.C  C_2.D  C_2.E  C_3.A  C_3.B  C_3.C  C_3.D   C_3.E            
1      4      6      8      C_1    2      4      6      1      C_2    3      4      2      7      C_3                
3      56     7      8      C_1    2      3      6      8      C_2    2      1      5      1      C_3             
2      4      6      1      C_1    7      8      3      4      C_2                   
                                   2      3      6      8      C_2          
                                   1      4      6      8      C_2                                  
                                   2      3      5      6      C_2                      
                                   3      4      6      7      C_2
                                   1      9      6      1      C_2
```

however the code i used as shown below is not working for dividing the columns having different number of rows

```
wide<-cbind(C_1[C_1$E =="C_1",],C_1[C_1$E=="C_2",], C_1[C_1$E=="C_3",])
```

the code i used has following issues 
1. we need to mention specifically the number of classes in the specified column, 
2. naming the column names

i am looking for a code to get the data in desired format

thanks in advance

Comment: what you are trying to do here is not a good approach for any data problem. I would try to find another solution or explain what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Also did you have a look at `dcast` function?

Comment: i further want to extract some more features from these data and have to plot scatter plots for any two variables corresponding to C_1.E/ C_2.E and so on.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired output as mentioned in the question, i did the following process

step-1:

split the data frame in to lists using the following command

```
> split(DF[, -5], DF[, 5])
```

step-2:

then the following code is used to add a string to list's names

```
> colnames <- c("ABC", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD")

> for (i in seq_along(DF)){
   colnames(DF[[i]]) <- paste0(names(DF[i]), colnames) 
  }
```

step-3:

then the unequal sized lists can be combined in a single data frame using the qpcR library as follows:

```
> library(qpcR)  ## required for combining multiple dataframes from a lists

> sample2 <- do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, DF) # combines multiple dataframes in a list by column vise irrespective of row sizes
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to use `split()`:

```
split(DF[, -5], DF[, 5])
$C_1
  A  B C D
1 1  4 6 8
2 3 56 7 8
3 2  4 6 1

$C_2
   A B C D
4  2 4 6 1
5  2 3 6 8
6  7 8 3 4
7  2 3 6 8
8  1 4 6 8
9  2 3 5 6
10 3 4 6 7
11 1 9 6 1

$C_3
   A B C D
12 3 4 2 7
13 2 1 5 1
```

If you are interested in a list of items formatted like you have, `stack()` can assist with the process:

```
#reshape to long
stacked = data.frame(E = DF[, 5], stack(DF[, -5]))

#unite the "C_1, C_2, C3" field with the "A, B, C, ..." field
stacked$split_ind = paste0(stacked$E, '.', stacked$ind)

#split
split(stacked[, 2], stacked$split_ind)

$C_1.A
[1] 1 3 2

$C_1.B
[1]  4 56  4

$C_1.C
[1] 6 7 6

$C_1.D
[1] 8 8 1

$C_2.A
[1] 2 2 7 2 1 2 3 1

$C_2.B
[1] 4 3 8 3 4 3 4 9

$C_2.C
[1] 6 6 3 6 6 5 6 6

$C_2.D
[1] 1 8 4 8 8 6 7 1

$C_3.A
[1] 3 2

$C_3.B
[1] 4 1

$C_3.C
[1] 2 5

$C_3.D
[1] 7 1
```

Comment: the split function is dividing the data into lists. however i am expecting the data to be in the desired format as shown in the question. all the sub data frames of unequal size should be in the same data frame side by side.

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible. A ```data.frame``` cannot have vectors of unequal lengths.

Comment: @Kumar, can you make the intended output in code? i.e ```data.frame(C_1.A = c(...), C_2.B = c(...), ...)```

Comment: u mean input data or output data?

Comment: Output data. Thanks.